# XPath to select string value of element but with <br/> replaced with newline?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, xpath-1.0

Is it possible to call xpath `normalize-space()` on html with displaying `<br>`, `<br/>` as new line? XPath version is 1.0

We parse articles from websites. Example of real HTML code:

```
<div id="someid">
    <img src="https://habrastorage.org/webt/ej/ye/hp/ejyehp08ercmqzlhzh3um6mtukm.jpeg"><br>
    <br>
    Организовать удаленный доступ для сотрудников — задача прикладная. Решений на рынке немало, при этом, и подводных камней достаточно. Под катом рассказ о нашем «чемодане», который раскладывается быстро и удобно за 30 минут. Просьба не воспринимать это как рекламный BS, поскольку внутри реальная инструкция по применению.<a name="habracut"></a><br>
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.parallels.com/ru/products/ras/remote-application-server/">Parallels Remote Application Server</a> (RAS) — это комплексное средство для доставки виртуальных приложений и рабочих столов, позволяющее работать с приложениями и данными с любого устройства, в том числе мобильного. Мы понимаем, что такие решения хочется сначала протестировать в конкретных условиях, прежде чем принимать решение о покупке.     <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

Problem not in extracting text from site. Problem is that `normalize-space` is remove all tags include `<br>`. As a result we have one long text line. I need text line with breaks.

Expected result:

```
Организовать удаленный доступ для сотрудников — задача прикладная. Решений на рынке немало, при этом, и подводных камней достаточно. Под катом рассказ о нашем «чемодане», который раскладывается быстро и удобно за 30 минут. Просьба не воспринимать это как рекламный BS, поскольку внутри реальная инструкция по применению.

Parallels Remote Application Server(RAS) — это комплексное средство для доставки виртуальных приложений и рабочих столов, позволяющее работать с приложениями и данными с любого устройства, в том числе мобильного. Мы понимаем, что такие решения хочется сначала протестировать в конкретных условиях, прежде чем принимать решение о покупке.
```

Comment: 1) Is there any specific reason why you want to use `normalize-space()`? 2) Do you want to get those 2 substrings as single string or as list of 2 strings? 3) Share your XPath

Comment: @Andersson 1) We need text with no html tags, but with breakpoints. 2) We can have from 1 to ∞ <br> tags. We crawl articles.

Comment: Are you assured that `br` is the only element type in your mixed content?

Comment: @kjhughes question updated

Comment: @ArtemDumanov, There is no parent tag for all those text nodes in provided piece of HTML. Can you update HTML again?

Comment: @Andersson updated

Comment: Did you try simple `//div[@id="someid"]/string()`?

Comment: @Andersson problem not in extracting text from site. Problem is that `normalize-space` is remove all tags include `<br>`. As a result we have one long text line. I need text line with breaks.

Comment: What tool do you use to parse HTML?

Comment: @Andersson python, scrapy framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I din't solve this issue with xpath. This solution is suitable for python (scrapy framework), but algorithm is the same for other languages too.

```
parsed_text = remove_tags(response.xpath(record['xpath_text']).extract_first())
text = re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n\n' , parsed_text).strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
string-join(
for $n in (//div[@id="someid"]//node()[self::br or self::text()]) 
    return if (name($n)='br') 
           then codepoints-to-string(10)
           else $n, '')
```

will join the strings of all text node descendants of the targeted `div`, replacing all `br` elements with newlines.

Comment: I checked xpath version, and it is 1.0. Is it possible to do the same with xpath 1.0? Anyway, thanks for your response

Comment: Question was tagged as XPath 2.0 when I answered.  (It's since been edited.)

Comment: I suspect that with only XPath 1.0 you'll not be able to find a purely XPath-based solution -- will have to write code in hosting language.

Comment: So, I did it with python